# Views contact details and get phone number selected by user

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract

I want to display the native android contacts list and then once the user picks a contact, i would like to move to the next native screen where it shows the details of the contact (like phone numbers, email, etc). 
Now once the user selects either an email address or a phone number, I would then like to get that data back to my original activity and do further processing.

I know that I could use

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI), REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACT);
```

and then myself parse the contact using `getContentResolver().query()` and then store each of the required fields. Then  finally display on a separate activity as contact details and then once the user chooses any one of the phone numbers or emails, then i use that to do further processing.

I tried to do the following inside `onActivityResult()`:

```
Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, contactData);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACT_DETAIL);
```

This displays the details of the contact but when the user selects a particular number, android calls it instead of passing it back to me in the previous activity.

But I would like to use the native screens if possible and it would require a lot less parsing and no extra activities/fragments.

Could someone suggest how to go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get contact details from phone contact doing this way

```
 Uri uri = data.getData();
    String[] projection    = new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};

    Cursor people = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

    int indexName = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int indexNumber = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
  int type = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);

    people.moveToFirst();
    do {
        String name   = people.getString(indexName);
        String number = people.getString(indexNumber);
        System.out.println(name+number);

    } while (people.moveToNext());
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
 Uri contactData = data.getData();
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Cursor c = cr.query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                String id = c
                        .getString(c
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                String hasPhone = c
                        .getString(c
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

                if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                    Cursor phones = getContentResolver()
                            .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                    null,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                            + " = " + id, null, null);
                    phones.moveToFirst();
                    String cNumber = phones
                            .getString(phones
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cNumber,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    String nameContact = c
                            .getString(c
                                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            // contact number = cNumber
            //contact name = nameContact
}
}
```

Comment: This would work if the user picks one contact from the contact list. It would return data which we would then parse as above. I was hoping for something so that after user picks a contact the flow goes to contact details page and  then when the user picks a particular phone number, then it returns that to use is some data that we use further